# jquery add <br> to h2 if h2 contains this word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if the h2 has the word ply i want to add a break.

the titles are dynamically called, the site is html so i can't use php on anything.

heres the h2

11/400-5 4 PLY EXPERIMENTAL TIRE AIRCRAFT TIRE

want it to look like this

11/400-5 4 PLY
EXPERIMENTAL TIRE AIRCRAFT TIRE

so any title that has the word PLY in it will add a break right after the word.

probably pretty easy for all yous out there =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/DbJ2V/

```
$('h2:contains(" PLY ")').html( function(i,htm) {
     return htm.replace(" PLY ", " PLY<br/>");
});
```

Comment: what if you got tabs, not spaces, at either side?

Comment: i can just tweak the contents i can see how it works. thanks this works great

Answer (score 3):

Let's try answer instead of commenting:

```
$("h2:contains('PLY')").each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/(\WPLY\W)/g, "$1<br />"));
});
```

First we look for any h2 with the text '`PLY`', then replace it, if it is indeed not part of a word (for example, `-PLY` would match, `_PLY` wouldn't, blame regexes for what is part of a word and what is not), with the same content plus a `<br />`.

Comment: `\b` would be good too, instead of `\W`, depends on choice. I really haven't put much thought to which would be best in this case (and indeed, a simple `\s` or just spaces could be enough).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#content h2:contains(' PLY ')").each(function(k,v) {
        t = $(v).text();
        $(v).html(t.replace(" PLY ", " PLY<br/>"));
    }); 
});
```